# How to write unit test for the fact that trait was included in class(and overriding existing method)

Tags: php, include, phpunit, traits

A.php

```
class Parent {

    protected function myFunc() {

    }
}
```

B.php

```
include Neighbour
class Child extends Parent {


}
```

Neighbour.php

```
trait Neighbour {
     protected function myFunc() {

    }
}
```

I need to write a tests for `Child` class. This class extended from `Parent` class and has method inherited `myFunc()`. I include trait in this class which has own `myFunc()` method. Is there any graceful way to unit test this fact?

Comment: employing unit (and not only unit-) testing practice you test and ensure the behaviour of your code. i.e. you test how the code works by executing it and expecting smth to happen (or not to happen), but not by ensuring the code consists of specific letters, words, lines, etc. So you can test the behaviour of `Child` and expect some specific result of its `myFunc`. As far as I understood your intent, its result (or impact) is to be different from `Parent`'s `myFunc`

Comment: Yes, you are right and thanks for the answer. But imagine this trait is from other vendor(library). I must write unit test for not mine code in this case. And this trait already covered. Logically i have to test only the fact i enabled it in my class right? But looks like i don't have other options, technically.

Comment: i see your point (about the fact a trait can be from other codebase). still if you include the trait in your code you definetly expect some behaviour from it, don't you? and thus you expect that behaviour to belong to object from your codebase )))  To speak broader (and more with personal preferences, too) traits are somewhat weird and not quite test-friendly in the sense that draws out of the the case you've mentioned. A lot of questions arise when using them. Skipping those and being closer to your case i'd consider doing some testing just to be sure method from trait got hit. Or refactor ))

Answer (score 0):

### No straightforward way except using [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and [spl_object_hash](http://php.net/spl_object_hash)

I started off the answer with an obvious "Just use Reflection to get info about the method", but it surprisingly turned out to be more complicated. Read [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30805527/4725998) for more details.